# Cost comparison of DynamoDB vs mongodb vs RDS SQL DB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, rds

I am right now using dynamodb in my app which is not in production yet. I have app that shows following items in different views

```
1) show list of orders posted by other users from last 3 days to the user
2) show list of orders that user created 
3) show list of orders that user have submitted bids
```

Think of it as ebay except user post order for tasks and other users bids on it. Also instead of searching function in ebay, we have tree like structure to show and organize all orders

```
level1 - list of states that have available orders from last 3 days, 
level2- list of cities in state that have available orders from last 3 days,
level3- all orders from last 3 days in the city
```

Right now my architecture is doing lots of reads and write to perform above operations and it is very costly. Rightnow we are just testing the app and has only 3 users and 100 orders created and it is costing me 2$ everyday. This cost will be ridiculously high when I will have thousands of users and thousands of orders in production. In order to do the operation I am doing full scan of full order collection.

Since this dynamodb is expensive, I am thinking about switching to mongodb. I only have experience with mongodb by running it locally but never deployed it on AWS or have any production experience. However, I am willing to do/learn to decrease cost. Also, I am new to AWS. I am thinking that mongodb will be cheap option as it is not charged based on read and write.

Another option is going to RDS SQL DB but for that I have to redesign database and do lot of changes.

Please give me suggestion on what will be the cheapest and best option in my case. Thank you.

Comment: Please revised your question and provide more details. It is meaningless to say dynamo DB expensive without info like provisioning and throughput results.

Comment: There's something missing from this picture. The free tier for DynamoDB is [massively generous](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/), no way would you be getting charged $2/day. "For a little less than $0.25/day ($7.50/month), you could support an application that performs 1 million writes and reads per day, 100K read requests from Streams, and stores 1 GB of data."

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB is cheap. You could have a look at using the [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/) cloud offering, which is comparable cheap as well, but that may not be much cheaper. You are trying to compare apples with oranges.

However, it looks more like a design problem. You somehow seem to be regularly do some queries based on "the last 3 days", you should look at doing those queries not too often and cache those results using [ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/).

*Updated:*
If you are doing full collection scans than there is something else wrong as well. You need to avoid these. Make use of the global secondary indexes if you haven't done so yet. You could consider adding some index data only collections if you already used up the five secondaries.

In regard to MongoDB it's way more flexible for creating indexes as you can create indexes covering more than two fields(e.g. city, state and date) and you can create much more than five indexes, which would certainly ease your full scan scenarios. In addition you would be able to use the powerful aggregation framework for some of your queries. You should still consider caching those queries with ElastiCache (redis/memcached).

Comment: Dynamo price is subjective. Some admin over-provisioned instead of checking the consumed provision I/O and adjust accordingly, pretty tedious task if not knowing all those AWS logging and API tools.

Comment: I don't understand the recommendation to use ElastiCache to cache query results. That's a server that runs 24/7, and even a `t2.small` would cost $24/mo to run. Doesn't seem like a cost-effective way to cache query results. I was under the impression ElastiCache was intended for high-velocity data (e.g. performing tens of thousands of read/write operations per second).

Comment: @ffxsam It's a question of scaling out. If you have to pay 1000$/month and do those queries which return the same results for many users you could probably cut the 1000$ to 300$ by caching the results using 2 small elasticache instances. Excluding coding and maintenance you could probably save 700$ by paying 60$ for Elasticache.